# VSFTP Delete only some files?

Tags: vsftpd

I'm very new to Linux but have been making some slow progress.  I've got an issue with `vsftp` where I can delete SOME directories and files but not all.

Some information:

1. These are existing files on a hd taken from a windows machine.
2. All files can be accessed and read by vsftp.  Only some cannot be deleted.
3. I can delete, move, rename etc.. all files from the CLI.
4. When I view the log file while trying to delete these files/folders it says:

   ```
   Thu Oct  1 10:41:17 2015 [pid 14832] CONNECT: Client "my.ip.address"

   Thu Oct  1 10:41:19 2015 [pid 14831] [myusername] FAIL LOGIN: Client "my.ip.address"
   ```
5. On the files I CAN delete it says OK LOGIN:
6. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.3

Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The ability to "delete" files is really the ability to "write" the directory containing the files. The permission of the directory containing the file governs, not the file's permission. Compare the access of the VSFTP user to the cli user.

Comment: l.  I did get it working. However I didn't figure out what was going on. I do suspect a permission issue with vsftp though. I have vsftp set up to use my local user account to log in. Which does have write permissions.

I set up sftp and that seems to work. The same user as ftp. I'd rather be using sftp anyway.